# grub permission error

Tags: debian, permissions, grub-legacy

I had some package and a kernel update today on my Debian work computer. When running sudo apt-get install I get the following:

```
paul@icarus:~$ sudo apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libwine-gecko-1.4
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 (3.2.65-1) ...
Running depmod.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-4-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-4-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw for module r8169
W: TMPDIR is mounted noexec, will not cache run scripts.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.2.0-4-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-4-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
grub-mkconfig: You must run this as root
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64.postinst line 696.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64
N: Ignoring file 'out.log' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'err.log' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'out.log' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'err.log' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'out.log' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'err.log' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Grub looks like it is causing problems. But if I just run grub-mkconfig as root or with sudo I still get a permission error:

```
root@icarus:~# grub-mkconfig
grub-mkconfig: You must run this as root

paul@icarus:~$ sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-mkconfig: You must run this as root
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
~$ su
password:
root@ ~$ grub-mkconfig > /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

it should work. because its permission, it must be *root* user, not normal user even using *sudo*. maybe it is a new policy from debian.